# Map Java Stream to Map of Objects with Object as Key

Tags: java-8, java-stream, collectors

I have some classes and I am doing some work in a List<WorkDay> which contains a List<LedgerItem>, I have everything working but one part. Well it works, but not exactly how I would like it to.

```
public Stream<Map<WorkDay, Set<LedgerItem>>> adjustWorkDays(List<WorkDay> workDays) {        
    return workDays.stream()
            .sorted((d1,d2) -> d1.getCreated().compareTo(d2.getCreated()))
            .map(day -> createGroupByWorkDay(day))/*need it to collect here*/;
}
```

If you can see the return type is `Stream<Map<WorkDay, Set<LedgerItem>>>` but I want to map this out of the Stream as `Map<WorkDay, Set<LedgerItem>>` with a collector but just cannot seem to get `Collectors.toMap()` syntax to do anything but break.

Like I said, everything works perfectly, so I dont need anything outside of the mapping to work.

Just FYI: `createGroupByWorkDay` returns `Map<WorkDay, Set<LedgerItem>>` already but only accepts a single `WorkDay` as this is a requirement so I cannot change the way this is executed...

thanks in advance

EDIT: 
So the method that I have `createGroupByWorkDay` that is not listed here works perfectly as expected, and will never be changed. It returns the correct type of `Map<WorkDay, Set<LedgerItem>>` but only has a signature for one WorkDay like this `createGroupByWorkDay(WorkDay day)` to the method in question in the original comment uses that to build individual Maps which are grouped by WorkDay and returns, but there could be N number of those, so the method `public Stream<Map<WorkDay, Set<LedgerItem>>> adjustWorkDays(List<WorkDay> workDays)` should return all of those Maps collected into one map in the collector. If that makes any sense?

Comment: `workDays.stream()
            .sorted((d1,d2) -> d1.getCreated().compareTo(d2.getCreated())).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(WorkDay::getDay,Collectors.toSet()));`

Comment: I've tried exactly this, and it just doesn't want to work this way, which is why I am so baffled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is not clear to me. But I guess you may be asking for something like this?

```
Map<WorkDay, List<LedgerItem>> result = workDays.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), WorkDay::getLedgerItems));
```

If not please explain your problem statement clearly. This is just a guess.

Here's an update,

```
Map<WorkDay, List<LedgerItem>> result = workDays.stream()
    .map(d -> createGroupByWorkDay(d))
    .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Comment: You nailed it, got me exactly what I needed.